# Lua syntax error expected '(' near update_rotation

Tags: lua, watchmaker

[image: Screen shot of error message]The syntax error does not appear until I type the = for the variable assignment on the next line. App is Watchmaker.

Complete code

```
-- Calculate rotation angle based on current time
function update_rotation()
    local current_hour = os.date("%H")
    local rotation_angle = (current_hour / 24) * 360
    return rotation_angle
end

-- Update rotation every minute
function on_minute()
    local rotation = update_rotation()
    your_control.rotation = rotation
end
```

I am expecting this code to rotate a watch hand around the face once in each 24 hours.

Comment: You could simplify your code to `
function on_minute()
    your_control.rotation = os.date '%H' * 15
end`

Comment: Makes sense but now I get the same error for on_minute

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error on 5.4.6 or on LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3. Are you sure this is the actual code that's causing the error?

Comment: The mistake is somewhere outside this code fragment

Comment: This is the actual code. I copy and pasted to create this post. I thought I attached a screenshot as well as the code in text form, but I don't see it now.

This code fragment is the only code there is.

I am assuming there is an error somewhere other than where indicated, and the parser is misdiagnosing it, but I can't see any other error.